# Create an HTML file that uses the DOM to swap the contents of two paragraph each time the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html

Create an HTML file that uses the DOM to swap the contents of one paragraph with the contents of a second paragraph each time the user clicks a button.

Here's the code I got, but it's still not working. Anyone know what's wrong?

`

```
<script>
    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");

    p1.addEventListener("click", swap);
    p2.addEventListener("click", swap);

    function swap() {
        var p1Text = p1.textContent;
        p1.textContent = p2.textContent;  
        p2.textContent = p1Text;
    }
</script>
```

`<body>`
    `<p id="p1">Paragraph1</p>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p id="p2">Paragraph2</p>`

```
<button id="p1,p2">Swap</button>
```

`</body>`
`

Comment: This is my first web programming class... please don't expect me to know everything, I already tried my best.

Answer (score 0):

...you attached the swap function to only clicking p1 or p2 (which works). You didn't attach anything to the button.

If you were thinking `id="p1,p2"` does something magic, it doesn't.

Comment: so is should it be  onclick ="swap()" ?